# ajax is returning id in wrong format

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a problem where I am getting an id from a selected checkbox, then it sends it to a delete method and it then passes the id to a stored procedure. The problem I am having though is it is returning my id in a wrong format ("232,4323") instead of ("232","4323") so when it comes to passing in values to the stored procedure, it craps out because of the string format.
Here is my code in the aspx.

```
function doTheDelete(doIDeleteTimeTracker) {
    var selectedTimeTrackerList = getSelectedTimeTrackerIDs();
    if (selectedTimeTrackerList.length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //url: "/Tasks/ViewTasks.aspx/deleteTasksAndLinkedItems",
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/TimeTrackers/ViewTimeTrackers.aspx/deleteSelectedTimeTracker")%>',
            data: "{'DeleteTimeTracker' : '" + doIDeleteTimeTracker + "'," + "'TimeBill': ['" + selectedTimeTrackerList.join(',') + "']}",
            //dataaaaaa
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var ss = data.d;
                if (ss.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {
                        $.noty.consumeAlert({ layout: 'center', type: 'error', dismissQueue: true });
                        alert(ss[i]);
                    }
                }
                $("#viewTimeTrackersGrid").flexReload();
                showMessage('Successfully Removed Time Tracker');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $.noty.consumeAlert({ layout: 'center', type: 'error', dismissQueue: true, modal: true });
                alert('Error Deleting Time Tracker');
                if (window.console) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        showMessage('No time tracker(s) are selected.');
    }
}
```

and here is my delete method in the code behind.

```
public static string[] deleteSelectedExpense(bool DeleteExpenses, String[] ExpId)
{
    var rList = new List<string>();
    //var canDeleteTasks = false;
    //var canDeleteTrackers = false;
    var canDeleteExpenses = false;
    var investigatorID = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["InvestigatorID"];
    var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ToString());
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("p_Admin_Permissions_CanDeleteExpenses", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvestigatorID", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@InvestigatorID"].Value = investigatorID;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        canDeleteExpenses = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (SqlException sql)
    {
        if (!rList.Contains("Can not connect to the database. Please try again."))
            rList.Add("Can not connect to the database. Please try again.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (!rList.Contains("An Error Occured"))
            rList.Add("An Error Occured");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Close();
    }

    if (canDeleteExpenses)
    {
        foreach (var expense in ExpId)// expense ends up beng ("232,423") instead of just taking 1 string at a time ("232").....("423")...
        {

            if (canDeleteExpenses)
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OSCIDConnectionString"].ToString());
                cmd = new SqlCommand("p_CaseFiles_Expenses_DeleteExpenses", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExpID", SqlDbType.Int));
                cmd.Parameters["@ExpID"].Value = int.Parse(expense);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Message", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                cmd.Parameters["@Message"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException sql)
                {
                    if (!rList.Contains("Error Connecting to the Database. Unable To Delete Expense(s)."))
                        rList.Add("Error Connecting to the Database. Unable To Delete Expense(s).");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (!rList.Contains("An Error Occured"))
                        rList.Add("An Error Occured");
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        conn.Close();
                }
            }
            else if (!canDeleteExpenses)
            {
                rList.Add("You do not have permission to delete Expenses");
            }
            else
            {
                if (!rList.Contains("You do not have permission to delete the Expense(s)."))
                    rList.Add("You do not have permission to delete the Expense(s).");
            }
        }
    }
    return rList.ToArray();
}
```

I am guessing it could be in the "Data :" in the ajax call formatting for the array(I've tried a few things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the help gents. I managed to fix it. Solution was to do this:

```
 "'ExpId': ['" + selectedExpensesList.join('\',\'') + "']}",
```

instead of :

```
 "'ExpId': ['" + selectedExpensesList.join(',') + "']}",
```

adding the extra ' seemed to work. It then manages to take each id seperately instead of taking the entire array and pooping on me

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
... 'TimeBill': ['" + selectedTimeTrackerList.join('","') + "']}" ...
```

Although a better solution would be to create a full javascript object with the required properties and apss it as an argument. BTW you may want to consider using something like PageMethods instead of jQuery if you are calling this method only on this page.

Comment: i tried it but when it gets to the code behind part it returns the string format as "232\","32\". And for some reason in the foreach loop, it doesn't grab foreach. It for some reason takes the entire array instead of iterating it

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to create a string to send as `Data`, you can send a json object instead.

```
Data: { 
        DeleteTimeTracker: doIDeleteTimeTracker, 
        TimeBill: selectedTimeTrackerList 
      }, ...
```

Comment: I will try it. And for some reason in the foreach loop, it doesn't grab foreach. It for some reason takes the entire array instead of iterating it

Comment: I'm not a big asp.net user, but usually you don't use `foreach` for array types.  I usually use a for loop like `for(int i = 0; i < ExpId.length; i++) var id = ExpId[i];`.

Comment: i would have used a for loop as well, but the previous person who coded this piece was using a foreach so i didn't want to alter too much. I will try it. I have also tried your method above, but the call to the method never gets made because it breaks at Data: {...